# pandas pyodbc unicode issues u\2013

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc, python-unicode

I am using a mac with python 2.7 and pyodbc to query data from Microsoft Sql server.
There is a timestamp column which shows up as datetime64[ns] in my dataframe

Structure of the program -

```
SQLCommand = (" SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 from xyztable ") 
DF = pd.read_sql(SQLCommand,cnxn)

# extracting Day and month by converting to dt 
DF['TS']=DF['TS'].dt.strftime('%d%m%')
# Create labels from Categories (string type data column in SQL table), replacing each category
DF['Flag']= DF['CODE']
DF.dtypes


TS         datetime64[ns]
TIWOR            object
CODES           object
T-enc                int8
TS                    object
TS_HHMM               object
TS_DD                  int64
TS_DDMM                int64
Flag              object
dtype: object

# I am able to replace all categories but it fails at this step as u\2013 appears in the middle of string 
DF['Flag'].unique()
array([0, 1, nan, u'Dev \u2013 Env'], dtype=object) 

# All attempts to find and replace are not working, some records have 'nan' values and DF.dropna does not work.
```

Attempts to fix

1. Various stack overflow articles have been referred but it did not help.
2. exported Sql query output into a CSV file and loaded into Dataframe, still same issue . 
   `DF.to_csv('~/SQLoutput.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')`
3. exported sql query output into an excel file and loaded into dataframe, still same issue 
   `DF=pd.read_excel('/Users/User1/SQLoutput.xlsx',sheet_name=0,encoding='utf-8')`
4. added `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-` at beginning of code, did not help
5. Verified pyodbc settings, no problem.
   `tsql -S sqlservername -U Username -P Password`

Comment: what datetype is the column in the database? also, what is the value for that record? is it truly '\u2013` in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Not tried though in pandas, but you might be able to resolve `unicode` issues using (This is just sample for one record, try applying same for entire column):

```
import unidecode
record = unidecode.unidecode_expect_nonascii(record)
```